# Laravel - form action after authentication

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I'd like to know how I can send my form to a method when the auth middleware comes in the way.

When I submit the form, auth middleware checks if the user is logged in. If not the user will be asked to log in. After a successful login, the user will be redirected to the form.
But I like the form to be sent once the login was successful.

Can anyone tell me what needs to be done to archive this?

Thanks in advance!

Andreas

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't authenticate the user before he can access the form?

Comment: @Remul Yeah, there is. It's a form where you can create a setup for a character for a game and see the benefits of the items. This feature should be available for just everyone. But when the user wanna save the config he has to be logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel Authentication. Run this command to generate Authentication

```
php artisan make:auth
```

On your Login Controller

```
\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php
```

Add this Method on Login Controller

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request,$user){
  if(auth::id()){
    return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
  } 
  return redirect('/user/dashboard');
}
```

On your formAction method check the user logged in or not by

```
  Auth::id();
```

if Authentication id not found then put your form data on Session and redirect user to logged in page and after logged in you can easily get the form submit data by session.

Comment: I have already implemented authentication. I asked how the form can be sent automatically after authentication. For now I can submit the form - then I will be redirected to the login (if im not logged in yet) and then I will be redirected to the form again and have to click on submit again. But I don't want the form to be sent once more.

Comment: If i am not getting wrong you want record a new Information while User logged in.

Comment: Let's assume it would be a comment function. Everyone can see the post. Under that post ypu have a comment input box and a submit button (save / post the comment). When you have clicked the submit button the method to store the comment will be called. But the auth middleware will check if the user is logged in. If so, the comment will be saved by the store method. If the user is not logged in, the auth middleware will redirect the user to the login page. After a successful login the comment then should be stored without having the user to write and send the comment again.

Comment: You can easily stored your data on Session while user not logged in and check  the session data while user logged in if session data have then direct store either return the comment form. I think this logic will help you to solve the prob.

Comment: Do you mind helping me out with some more example code, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184047/discussion-between-md-jubair-mizan-and-andreas-b).